# How to Import a Fire Simulation from One .blend to another

Tags: import, smoke-simulation

Say I made a really nice explosion in a .blend and then I want to take that same explosion and put it into another .blend file. I would need to copy all the involved objects, but would I also need to copy the bake folder? It seems like if I append the objects without copying the fire bake folder, it has to rebake. How can I do this such that I don't have to rebake?

Comment: Generally yes, you should copy the folder with baked files (called as bakecache_filename IIRC) and move it to the folder with the new file. To make the smoke in new file actually use this sim I think you need to enable External from [baking options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/baking.html) and provide it with the folder name. It worked for me but I needed to rename files for some reason.